# Is a uniformly charged conducting plate the same as a uniformly charged conducting sheet?

Tags: electrostatics, terminology

Is it correct that a uniformly charged ***conducting*** plate is made up of two charged conducting sheets, that is, a charged ***conducting*** plate consists of four surfaces?

Comment: Generally not.  But you should give us more specifics for *us* to understand what *you* don't understand.

Comment: ok i got it...actually a charged conducting plate is made up of only two surfaces and a charged sheet is considered as a single surface only....earlier i was wrong...

Comment: I think what you may be getting to is that the charges gather on either side of a metal plate.  If we consider a "plate" to have thickness and a "sheet" to be infinitely thin, then this makes sense, although four surfaces makes sense in no scenario.  By these definitions a charged "sheet" would have a single plane of charge, and a "plate" would have two planes of charges - on either face.

Answer (score 2):

For a charged sheet, it is only charge that makes up the thing, there is nothing in between.There is a single layer of charge. But a charged plate has two layers of it. It is better to think like this if you are trying to find out the fields due to them.